# Are feature ids in QGIS and ArcMap stored differently?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, field-mapping

I have a shapefile that I use as a layer in ArcMap. Opening the attribute table, shows a fid starting with 0 for the features. If I attach the same shapefile in QGIS and open the attribute table, the features increment from 1. Copying and pasting the table into Excel gives me an FID field for Arc but not for QGIS. However, Copying the layer from QGIS into SQL Server gives me a table with a key field "qgs_fid" starting with 1.

Does this mean that I cannot treat the fid as a key field that is associated with the record for joins and relates, especially when combining with external data? Does the fid or qgs_fid change if records are inserted or deleted?

Comment: I think the FID in Arc and the ID in QGIS are just used by for referencing the row. You will find if you import the Shapefile in a Geodatabase the FID will change to OID. As a rule dont use these as key fields in Joins etc, raher create a new field ad create the key field that way.

Comment: Within ArcGIS, the shapefile FID field is a virtual column, with a zero-based record number, not a dBase entity. If you create a FID column in dBase, it is actually renamed to allow the virtual column to have its required name. It is unwise to use physical ordering as a join key if edits could occur.

Comment: So my understanding of the above comments is that there is no key field in a shapefile or possibly a file geodatabase table